# How to determine range key from index name even when Pk, SK are passed

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-index

I am trying to connect to dynamoDB and fetching data. This is how my code looks.
I tried catching the exception. It says

> Unable to determine range key from index name.

**CustomerManager.cs**

```
  public async Task<List<CustomerResponse>> GetCustomers()
    {
        var myCustomers = await m_CustomerEngine.GetSitesWithClientDetails();
        if (myCustomers == null) return null;

        var siteMonitors = new List<Monitor>();
        var names = new List<string>
        {
            "SITE"
        };
        var running = await m_MonitorEngine.QueryIndexItems("SITE:RUNNING", QueryOperator.BeginsWith, names, "GSI-Reverse").ConfigureAwait(false);
        var notRunning = await m_MonitorEngine.QueryIndexItems("SITE:NOTRUNNING", QueryOperator.BeginsWith, names, "GSI-Reverse").ConfigureAwait(false);

        if (running != null && running.Count > 0) siteMonitors.AddRange(running);

        if (notRunning != null && notRunning.Count > 0) siteMonitors.AddRange(notRunning);

        // return MapDynamoCustomerStatus(dCustomers, siteMonitors);
        return MapMySqlCustomerStatus(myCustomers, siteMonitors);
    }
```

**Data Model**

```
[DynamoDBTable("xyz")]
public class Monitor
{
    [DynamoDBHashKey("PK")]
    public string Site { get; set; }

    [DynamoDBRangeKey("SK")]
    public string Service { get; set; }

    [DynamoDBProperty("_rawData")]
    public string RawData { get; set; }
}
```

**MonitorRepository.cs**

```
   public AsyncSearch<Monitor> QueryIndexItems(string hashKey, QueryOperator queryOperator, IEnumerable<object> values, string indexName)
    
    {
        try
        {
            var tableName = m_Configuration["DynamoDbTables:Monitor"] ?? "ClientMonitoring-qa";
            DynamoDBOperationConfig config = new DynamoDBOperationConfig
            {
                OverrideTableName = tableName,
                IndexName = indexName
            };
            var data = m_MonitorContext.QueryItems(hashKey, queryOperator, values, config);
            return data;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception($"Amazon error in MonitorRepository.QueryItems table operation! Error: {ex}");
        }
    }
```

**DynamoDBRepository.cs**

```
    public AsyncSearch<T> QueryItems(string hashKey, QueryOperator queryOperator, IEnumerable<object> values, DynamoDBOperationConfig config)
    {
        var data = base.QueryAsync<T>(hashKey, queryOperator, values, config);
        return data;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you have not defined `DynamoDBGlobalSecondaryIndexRangeKey`. If you have, can you share more of your code.

Comment: I have edited my code. Please have a look.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more? How to ensure that I have/haven't defined DynamoDBGlobalSecondaryIndexRangeKey? Please guide.

Comment: You're reading from an index, but from the code that you shared you have not annotated which variables are you index keys, you've only declared annotations for the base table.

Comment: How to fix the code? I am new to DynamoDB. Please guide

Comment: You need to annotate your GSI PK and GSI SK with the correct annotations for the data model, such as the one I shared.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DeclarativeTagsList.html